# Append all the files located in path made of wild card characters

Tags: linux, bash, echo, wildcard

I'm trying to add "aaa" to the "ami" files without specifying full path

I tried this:

```
echo "aaa" >> /home/thomas/*-bbb-*/ami
```

instead of typing each path separate such as /home/thomas/1-bbb-2/ami and /home/thomas/1-bbb-3/ami and so on

Or should I somehow search recursively for all the files named "ami" in /home/thomas/ and add them to a variable and then append all those files in that variable?

Comment: How many files do you have? Are your path have differences only in numbers: 1-bbb-1, 1-bbb-2, 1-bbb-3 etc?

Comment: Up to 150 files total. I just want to do in some more intelligent way than typing each path

Comment: You may or may not hit  `ARGMAX` by doing that though.

Comment: `files=(/home/thomas/[0-9]*-bbb-[0-9]*/ami); for f in "${files[@]}"; do echo 'aaa' >> "$f"; done` Might need to enable `shopt -s nullglob`

Answer (score 2):

Try using loop:

```
for i in `seq 150` #change 150 to your value
do
echo "aaa" > /home/thomas/1-bbb-$i/ami
done
```

This will work if your paths change in one place (like your example).

Comment: The path is changing in 2 places:  /home/thomas/*-bbb-*/ami Otherwise your suggestion works. Is there a way how to add the files to a variable and then just work with those? Because it is not going to be always 150 files and in your way there are errors because it would always be looking for exactly 150. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Save the file names  in an array.

```
files=(/home/thomas/[0-9]*-bbb-[0-9]*/ami)

for f in "${files[@]}"; do echo 'aaa' >> "$f"; done
```